# Probability of a random variable dependent on a parameter.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X_L$ be a random variable dependent on a parameter $L$, taking only discrete values between $0$ and $+\infty$. Let $\mu L$ be its expectation, where $\mu$ is a costant. Which conditions should I impose on $X_L$ in order to be true that there is a positive constant $C$ such that for every $L$ $\mathbb{P}(X_L > \mu L / 2  ) > C$?
Should I necessarily know how the variance depends on $L$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reverse Markov inequality. But for that you have to assume that $X_L$ is less or equal than an $a$ a.e. Then based on reverse Markov inequality for $d<\mu L$ you get: 
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_L>d )> \frac{\mu L-d}{a-d}
$$
Now choose $d=\frac{\mu L}{2}$ you get:

> $$
> \mathbb{P}(X_L>\frac{\mu L}{2})> \frac{1}{2\frac{a}{\mu L}-1}
> $$

To get a constant $C$ for all $L$, you have to assume that for all $X_L$ and $L$ there is a constant $C$, such that:
$$
X_L<C \mu L      \text{    a.e. }.
$$
For this you get

> $$
> \mathbb{P}(X_L>\frac{\mu L}{2})> \frac{1}{2C-1}
> $$

Another way is the use a modified Chebyshev inequality which is:
$$
P(d_1<X<d_2)\geq \frac{4[(\mu_x-d_1)(d_2-\mu_x)-\sigma_x^2]}{(d_2-d_1)^2}.
$$
For $d_1<\mu_x<d_2$ and $(\mu_x-d_1)(d_2-\mu_x)>\sigma_x^2$. Now using this you get:
$$
P(\frac{\mu L}{2}<X_L<a)\geq \frac{4[(\frac{\mu L}{2})(a-\mu L)-\sigma_x^2]}{(a-\frac{\mu L}{2})^2}.
$$
Now if you assume that $\sigma_x<\sqrt{C}\mu L$ for all L, take $a=(2C+\frac{3}{2})\mu L$ and we get:

$$
P(\frac{\mu L}{2}<X_L<a)\geq \frac{4[(\frac{\mu L}{2})(a-\mu L)-\sigma_x^2]}{(a-\frac{\mu L}{2})^2}\geq \frac{4[(\frac{1}{2})(2{C}+\frac{1}{2})-C]}{(2{C}+\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2})^2}=\frac{1}{(2{C}+1)^2}.
$$
Now you have:

> $$
> P(X_L>\frac{\mu L}{2})\geq P(\frac{\mu L}{2}<X_L<a)\geq \frac{1}{(2{C}+1)^2}.
> $$

Comment: Thanks, but I asked for a lower bound in order to show that the probability is greater than $0$ for all $L$. Second of all.. did you prove that the probability is not larger than 2?

Comment: @Lorenzo Reverse Markov gives you the lower bound. It was typo in my text. I corrected it. I removed also the Markov one because it was trivial as you said.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I would wait for other answers as in my case $X$ takes values up to infinity and then I cannot use your estimations...

Comment: @Logarenz I added something to the answer, Hope it is fine now.

Comment: Thanks but as I said I am interested in the case of unbounded random variable...

Comment: But if you look carefully you do not need to have any bound on $X_L$ for the last one. I modify again the text to make it totally understandable.

Comment: Ok so you impose a condition on the variance. Thanks.